# How to join 2 rows in database?

Tags: mysql, sql

I got some issues  while structuring my database and I would like to know how to solve the below question .

I have a table in database :

| id | id_study | writer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | writer1 |
| 2 | 1 | writer2 |
| 3 | 2 | writer3 |

Please help me how to combine above 2 table rows to produce output like below :

| id | id_study | writer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1,2 | 1 | writer1, writer2 |
| 3 | 2 | writer3 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) as id, id_study,GROUP_CONCAT(Writer) as Writer
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY id_study;
```